# PDO select where

Tags: php

I am brand new to PHP and mysql and am trying something here. In my HTML, I have one form where I enter a mileage and it's passed on to the PHP code and converted to an integer. Then I want to take that and check against the database to isolate the record I want so I can do some computations. In other words, if the mileage entered (I save it in a veriable called $term) is less than or equal to a mileage in the table, I want to use the record that matches this criteria. For example, I enter 45 miles and the table has records at 40 miles and 50 miles, I want to pick the 50 mile level. If the user puts in 51, I want to use the 50 level. Things like that.

It connects to the database nicely but I'm not sure how to structure this at the foreach statement.
I have the following:

```
$term = (int)$_POST['term'];

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=ratetable", $username, $password);

    /*** The SQL SELECT statement ***/
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM rates WHERE mileage<=term";
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
        {
        print $row['mileage'] .' - '. $row['ratepermile'] . '<br />';
        }

    /*** close the database connection ***/
    $dbh = null;
}
```

When I do this, I get an invalid argument supplied foreach().

Then I started looking around and saw statements that look like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM rates WHERE mileage<=:term' );
```

where the search parameter is passed and so on.

So now I'm confused about what the correct way is to select a single record in an ascending list of mileages in a database (the last matching record versus all that match) that satisfies a criteria or how to correctly structure the WHERE argument. Any suggestions?

Thank you for looking.

Comment: Look at the [`PDO::prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) manpage on how to use it for correctly passing variables. -- The problem didn't lie in the loop, but in the invalid SQL query; you didn't pass a variable, but specified an invalid column with the raw `<=term"`.

Comment: Yeah, it should be "WHERE mileage<=$term"

Comment: The "mileage<=:term" is more secure, and if you do a lot of PHP/MySQL programming, it's pretty cool and much more secure, but unnecessary if this is a quick fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would need to do is use a `WHERE` clause in combination with `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses.  For example to get the highest value that is less than or equal to a given search criteria you would do:

```
SELECT * FROM rates
WHERE mileage <= ?
ORDER BY mileage DESC
LIMIT 1
```

To get the lowest value that is greater than or equal to a given search value do:

```
SELECT * FROM rates
WHERE mileage >= ?
ORDER BY mileage ASC
LIMIT 1
```

As far as doing the actual PDO you would do something like this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM rates WHERE mileage <= ? ORDER BY mileage DESC LIMIT 1');
$stmt->execute(array($term));
$row_object = $stmt->fetchObject();
```

Comment: Oh! So this matches the results to the last matching record? I assume ? is the placeholder for whatever variable I'm using for the criteria, right? Thanks Mike!

Comment: @Shawn That is correct.  Also see updated answer for PDO usage example.

Comment: Thank you! Also, I'm guessing this pretty much eliminates iterating or using a foreach statement?

Comment: @Shawn Yes no need to loop the result set at all. You should however test the result of the `$dbh->prepare()` call to make sure it returns a PDOStatement and test the `$stmt->execute` return value to see if it is false (indicating a failure). I did not show these above in the example.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM rates WHERE mileage<=term";
```

What this means is select * from rates where the column mileage <= the column term. I do not think you have the column term as that should be a parameter.

You are right to take a look at parameters. The code should be something like:

```
$term = 150;
$sth = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM rates WHERE mileage<=?');
$sth->execute(array($term));
```

To get only one of the records you should order by a column and get only the LIMIT 1

```
$term = 150;
$sth = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM rates WHERE mileage<=? ORDER BY mileage DESC LIMIT 1');
$sth->execute(array($term));
```

Because you only want 1 row you can just do a $result=$sth->fetchColumn(); instead of the foreach.

Comment: Hi Mihai, so if I don't know the exact value of the parameter (since $term is a variable that holds whatever the user entered on the webpage), I'm still ok to keep that variable structured the way I had it? (converting the input into an integer) Thanks!

Comment: $term = 150; is just a placeholder, you can also do a $sth->execute(array($_POST['term'])); if you want. Because PDO statements are protected and because you are using parameters you can use it safely.